# How to return a non-editable PDF as a response?

Tags: java, pdf

I have a URL:

http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf

It contains an editable PDF. I have make it non-editable. I did so and kept it in the temp directory of a folder. Now i want to send the non-editable PDF as a response, when the user clicks this url, he must get the non-editable pdf. This is what I have done till now:

```
String strDirectoy ="C:\\Temp";
boolean success = (
    new File(strDirectoy)).mkdir();
    if (success) {
        System.out.println("Directory: " 
        + strDirectoy + " created");
    }  
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf");//C:\\fw4.pdf
PdfStamper stamp2 = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("C:\\Temp\\Flattened.pdf"));
AcroFields form2 = stamp2.getAcroFields();
stamp2.setFormFlattening(true);
stamp2.close();
```

Now i need to delete the `temp` folder as if it never existed and return the non-editable PDF as the response for the above specified URL.

How can i do this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'flatten' a PDF?

Comment: Making a pdf form non editable .

Comment: Is this server side code? Why don't just keep non-editable pdf separately and provide url to it, not to editable one?

Comment: Try creating a signed pdf and return to client. : http://itextpdf.sourceforge.net/howtosign.html

Comment: So, what you are saying is that, after i flatten the pdf and keep it in temp, i must provide a new url to the flattened pdf , which will pop up the flattened pdf. How do i create a new url with the flattened pdf ? Thanks

Comment: jayan, what is the use of signing the pdf ? I don't know much about it. But the pdf must be presented to the user as it would have been originally seen minus the editable text boxes. If i sign it(self-sign), i am going to incorporate personal info in it, which is not desirable .

Comment: You mean making a pdf form non-editable like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308861/how-can-i-make-pdf-form-read-only ?

Comment: yes exactly, you are right .

Comment: @Nikolay : yes this is server side code .

Comment: You might also want to tell us what your server side environment is. Do you provide a Java web application in some web application container (Tomcat? JBoss? Something else?) In that case you can flatten the form in memory whenever asked for it (unless it is too big) and, thus, do not have to care about temporary file resources. Or do you only have a static web site into which you regularly inject such non-editable copies of forms? In that case I don't see how you can do without some dynamically used storage. Or is your setup different still.

Comment: Okay, I have WAS 6.1 , which is my web server. If i have to flatten the form in it's memory , how can i do it ? I have a dynamic site, but the link to the pdf is gonna remain constant. Do you have any ideas/suggestions for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Write a Servlet.
- Flatten your pdf in a temporary file (using the
  `createTempFile()`  and `deleteOnExit()` methods of `java.io.File`).
- Use the `setContentType` of the HttpServletResponse to set the MIME type
  of the pdf.
- Write the contents of the temporary pdf file to the
  outputstream of the http response

Comment: Okay, will try this one and get back to you .